# How to create a new HTML checkbox via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, button, checkbox

I have defined a button in HTML which calls a function to create an object in my JS. In addition, i would like this button to "spawn" the creation of a new checkbox (with name and value depending on the former created object) in HTML, lets say in div id XY.

Though i suppose it's not important, here is my current stuff.

html

```
<input id="button" value="pick Brakiri" onclick="initiate('Brakiri')">
```

js

```
function initiate(faction){
calc = new Calc(faction)
}
```

I would like to avoid jQuery if possible.

thank you.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML

Comment: Could you explain better "with name and value depending on the former created object"? Otherwise `document.createElement` will be the way

Comment: `var i = document.createElement('input'); i.type='checkbox';`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create a functin for this. A example under where you pass in `name` and `id` and it returns a brand new element:

```
function createNewCheckboxt(name, id){
    var checkbox = document.createElement('input'); 
    checkbox.type= 'checkbox';
    checkbox.name = name;
    checkbox.id = id;
    return checkbox;
}
```

After you just need to choose where to add it into the DOM. Something like:

```
form.appendChild(createNewCheckboxt('theName', 'theID'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi i'm not sur if i understand your question but this the code to create a new checkbox via javascript :

```
var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
checkbox.type = "checkbox";
checkbox.name = "name";
checkbox.value = "value";
checkbox.id = "id";    
container.appendChild(checkbox);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `<input>` element with `type="checkbox"` by using the `document.createElement()` method.

This will work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to create a Checkbox.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    x.setAttribute("value", "abc");
    x.setAttribute("name", "xyz");

    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_checkbox.asp)**